# Correct way to update an RPM package in a local repository

Tags: centos7, rpm, update, repository

I made a local CentOS 7 repository ([here](https://www.fosslinux.com/6749/setup-local-yum-server-on-centos-7-guide.htm)) with custom packages built and it is working fine, the problem is in `yum update`. When I update the source of an RPM package, I either increase the epoch or the version number so yum detects its an update, I copy the new RPM package to the repo directory and on a client PC I do `yum install` or `yum update` to install/update the package and yum returns with error "No more mirrors to try" or something like that. The only way to make it work again is to recreate the local repo from scratch. So the question is, how do I properly update an RPM package in a CentOS 7 repo?

P.S: If I add a new package and do a `createrepo -v` it will tell me `No package available.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The good way to maintain local repo is to establish kind of replication process (`rsync`, `wget`) from the original site and then update the information in repo. The command to update is:

```
createrepo --update
```

To avoid `cd` to the repo directory you can use command on this way:

```
createrepo --update /path/to/repo/directory
```

EDIT: Also you can check if the yum cache file is corrupted (/var/cache/yum). Usually clean it/delete can help. You can check [here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/203603) for reference.

Comment: What about a local repo that contains packages I made?

Comment: @3bdalla, its the same. Just be careful when using `rsync` (it can delete files which are missing i.e. your packages). You can create second repo and keep packages there.

Comment: Actually I got the same error when I updated a package, incrementing epoch first then the version. I recreated the repo, installed the package first, then copied the new RPM to the repo location and did `createrepo --update` but I got `No packages marked for update`

Comment: Did you try to use command on this way: `createrepo --update /path/to/repo/directory`?

Comment: Yes, didn't work. I am inspecting the spec file if anything could help.

Comment: @3bdalla, something is broken... What is the filesystem where is repo storage? How this filesystem is mounted (options)?

Comment: XFS file system. The repo location is on an NFS. NFS mount options are `auto,noatime,nolock,bg,nfsvers=3,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800 0 0`. I think I would try a repo on a folder on my PC, NFS could have something to do.

Comment: @3bdalla, NFS can be the problem. Try on local filesystem (or on NFS server)

Comment: I got it. The problem was a corrupted yum cache. I had to delete `/var/cache/yum` to make it work (mentioned here: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/203603 ). Now if I change only the epoch in my spec file, it is detected as new RPM and it is updated. If you want, update your answer so I can accept it.